# CakePHP read blob of session-data in DatabaseSession

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP DatabaseSessions with the following structure:
[image]

When I query the data blob, I get back a stream.

[image]

So usually you want to read the data with the function stream_get_contents which returns me a string of the stream.

The content looks like this:

```
user|O:21:"App\Model\Entity\User":11:{s:14:" * _accessible";
```

What does that mean now? How can i get the data as a object? Unserialization didn't work so far.

Comment: If that is all data that is in there, then it's invalid, and you need to figure out why the data isn't being written properly. Also please try to describe the problem more detailed, "_doesn't work_" could mean anything.

Comment: Its not the full content, but its the head of the serialisation, what else information do you need for the unserialisation to not work, i mean its a simple function which returns a object in case it worked and false in case it didnt.

Comment: For starters the complete data, not just a snippet. Also there's very few situations in which `unserialize()` only returns `false`, usually it's accompanied by an error/notice that tells you the specific problematic offset (make sure that you've enable error reporting accordingly). Also it could return an _incomplete_ object, indicating for example a missing class.

Comment: i found the solution, it is as your last statement states, missing class, will you write an solution so i can mark it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for getting data ask the object right. So I think you can use cakephp build query framework it may help. Such as find(), find('list'), find('all') ..etc.

Example : 
for build in query:

```
$databaseSessions = $this->DatabaseSessions->find();
```

For custom query :

```
$query = $this->DatabaseSessions->find()
            ->select([
                'DatabaseSessions.id',
                'DatabaseSessions.create',
                'DatabaseSessions.modified',
                'DatabaseSessions.data',
                'DatabaseSessions.expired'
            ]);
```